# Se eliminan datos en SQLite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

he tenido un problema con mi bdd en android al parecer todo se debe a como tengo estructurado la parte de `onUpgrade`

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAJAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

en algunas ocaciones se me elimina toda la tabla, como podría hacer para que esto nunca pase y evitar perdida de información que realmente se necesita guardar.

> Codigo Completo de my clase BasedeDatos

```
public class BasedeDatos_AgroMovil extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "agromovil.db";
    public static final String TABLE_CAJAS = "cajas";

//constructor
    public BasedeDatos_AgroMovil(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }



@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String TABLA_CAJAS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CAJAS + " (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_FECHA + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_RANCHO + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_SECTOR + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_TRABAJADOR + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(TABLA_CAJAS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAJAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define que se actualice solo cuando la nueva versión sea mayor que la versión actual

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAJAS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El método `onUpgrade` se ejecuta cuando cambias la versión de la base de datos, es decir, cuando la actualizas y te ves forzado a subir su número de versión (DATABASE_VERSION), ya sea porque añades o quitas campos en las tablas o lo que sea. En este caso, tu estás borrando la base de datos cada vez que actualizas su versión.

Mientras, el método `onCreate` se ejecuta cuando se crea la base de datos.

Así, lo que tienes que hacer en caso de que la quieras actualizar y cambies su número de versión es:

1. Sacar todos los datos que quieras guardar en el método `onUpgrade`
2. Borrar la tabla
3. Crear las nuevas tablas
4. Introducir los datos

Si lo que quieres es no hacer nada, entonces no debes de cambiar la versión. Si quieres hacer alguna otra cosa y cambiar el número de versión, pero no borrarla, deberías de quitar el `Drop Table`, que lo que hace es borrarla siempre que exista.

Comment: entonces considerando mi ejemplo, no utilizar el método me afectaría en algo?

Comment: En este caso, si es la primera vez que vas a poner la base de datos y no vas a modificarla, no deberías de poner nada ene se método. Otra cosa es que estés probando cosas y quieras limpiar la base de datos para inicializarla, que sería como lo tienes. También podrías poner un `if` que compruebe que si la versión nueva es mayor que la vieja entonces ejecute el borrado y sino, nada.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es aplica para las clases que extienden de **[SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)** cuando se realiza una actualización de la aplicación se llama al método  [onUpgrade()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)), es aquí donde se valida si la versión es nueva (versionCode de aplicación), en tu caso la implementación de este método esta realizando un [DROP](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) de la tabla :

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAJAS);
      onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Dependiendo de tu aplicación existen tablas que al actualizar pueden ser removidas y creadas nuevamente, en otros casos se requiere que estos datos persistan, si requieres los mismos datos simplemente no llames la eliminación y creación de la tabla:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAJAS);
   // onCreate(db);
}
```